# MsgPack Woes - Destructor, pack_raw_body, Etc

Tags: c++, msgpack, soci

I am using `MsgPack` as part of a custom back-end I am creating for the [`SOCI` C++ database access API](http://soci.sourceforge.net/). Initially, some of my `SOCI` classes had `MsgPack::sbuffer` objects as member variables, but I ran into some problems in the destructor of my `SOCI` object - I believe the problem relates to the way that `SOCI` reference counts some of its objects and the memory that underlies the `MsgPack` object being freed multiple times.

In an attempt to remedy this problem, I decide to replace the `MsgPack::sbuffer` member variables with `std::vector<char>` member variables, and use these to fill the `MsgPack::sbuffer`s using the `pack_raw_body` method. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with this as well.

Please consider the following (pseudo-)code snippet...

```
msgpack::sbuffer buf1;
msgpack::packer<msgpack::sbuffer> bufPkr1(&buf1);
bufPkr1.pack_array(num);
for (int ndx = 0; ndx < num; ++ndx) {
  bufPkr1.pack_array(3);
  bufPkr1.pack(std::string("foo"));
  bufPkr1.pack(std::string("bar"));
  bufPrk1.pack(221);
}

std::vector<char> chrVct = std::vector<char>(buf1.size(), *buf1.data());

msgpack::unpacked unPkd1;
msgpack::unpack(&unPkd1, buf1.data(), buf1.size());

msgpack::object toStr1 = unPkd1.get();
std::cout << "MsgPack1: " << toStr1 << std::endl;

msgpack::sbuffer buf2;
msgpack::packer<msgpack::sbuffer> bufPkr2(&buf2);
bufPkr1.pack_raw(chrVct.size());
bufPkr1.pack_raw_body(chrVct.data(), chrVct.size());

msgpack::unpacked unPkd2;
msgpack::unpack(&unPkd2, buf2.data(), buf2.size());

msgpack::object toStr2 = unPkd2.get();
std::cout << "MsgPack2: " << toStr2 << std::endl;
```

Output...

```
MsgPack1: [["foo", "bar", 221], ["foo", "bar", 221], ["foo", "bar", 221],..., ["foo", "bar", 221]]
MsgPack2: ""
```

In general, I'm just having trouble figuring out how to work with the MsgPack objects and am finding the documentation/examples a little sparse. Any help that people can offer would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the quirks of the MsgPack API seems to have to do with the lifetime of the various MsgPack objects, as well as the objects/integral data types that are being packed *into* the MsgPack objects.

The above code *probably* would have worked better if I had followed this idiom...

```
msgpack::sbuffer buf1;
msgpack::packer<msgpack::sbuffer> bufPkr1(&buf1);
bufPkr1.pack_array(num);
for (int ndx = 0; ndx < num; ++ndx) {
  bufPkr1.pack_array(3);
  bufPkr1.pack(std::string("foo"));
  bufPkr1.pack(std::string("bar"));
  bufPrk1.pack(221);
}

msgpack::unpacked unPkd1;
msgpack::unpack(&unPkd1, buf1.data(), buf1.size());
const msgpack::object obj1 = respUnPk.get();

msgpack::sbuffer buf2;
msgpack::packer<msgpack::sbuffer> bufPkr2(&buf2);
bufPkr2.pack(obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to pack the data in buf1 as a raw binary image. Then you want to unpack it.

The first problem is the usage of the std::vector's constructor. See the comment P1 in the following code:

```
#include <msgpack.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int const num = 5;
    msgpack::sbuffer buf1;
    msgpack::packer<msgpack::sbuffer> bufPkr1(&buf1);
    bufPkr1.pack_array(num);
    for (int ndx = 0; ndx < num; ++ndx) {
        bufPkr1.pack_array(3);
        bufPkr1.pack(std::string("foo"));
        bufPkr1.pack(std::string("bar"));
        bufPkr1.pack(221);
    }

// P1
//  std::vector<char> chrVct = std::vector<char>(buf1.size(), *buf1.data());
    std::vector<char> chrVct = std::vector<char>(buf1.data(), static_cast<char*>(buf1.data()) + buf1.size());

    msgpack::unpacked unPkd1;
    msgpack::unpack(&unPkd1, buf1.data(), buf1.size());

    msgpack::object toStr1 = unPkd1.get();
    std::cout << "MsgPack1: " << toStr1 << std::endl;

    msgpack::sbuffer buf2;
    msgpack::packer<msgpack::sbuffer> bufPkr2(&buf2);

// P2
//  bufPkr1.pack_raw(chrVct.size());
//  bufPkr1.pack_raw_body(chrVct.data(), chrVct.size());
    bufPkr2.pack_raw(chrVct.size());
    bufPkr2.pack_raw_body(chrVct.data(), chrVct.size());

    msgpack::unpacked unPkd2;
    msgpack::unpack(&unPkd2, buf2.data(), buf2.size());

    msgpack::object toStr2 = unPkd2.get();
    std::cout << "MsgPack2: " << toStr2.via.raw.size << std::endl;
    std::for_each(toStr2.via.raw.ptr, toStr2.via.raw.ptr+toStr2.via.raw.size,
            [](char e) {
                std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (static_cast<int>(e) & 0xff) << ' ';
            });
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The std::vector's constructor in the original code is fill all the vector member to the same value that is passed as the second parameter.

That is the (2) of the following documentation:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

I believe that the third constructor, range version, should be used on this situation. So I replaced the original code with modified code.

The second problem is that bufPkr2 is never used. I guess that it is just typo. I commented out the original code and replaced it.

As the result of those modification, I got the following result:

```
MsgPack1: [["foo", "bar", 221], ["foo", "bar", 221], ["foo", "bar", 221], ["foo", "bar", 221], ["foo", "bar", 221]]
MsgPack2: 56
95 93 a3 66 6f 6f a3 62 61 72 cc dd 93 a3 66 6f 6f a3 62 61 72 cc dd 93 a3 66 6f 6f a3 62 61 72 cc dd 93 a3 66 6f 6f a3 62 61 72 cc dd 93 a3 66 6f 6f a3 62 61 72 cc dd
```